# Conky: if_match 95 > 'command output'

Tags: conky

```
${if_match 95 >= execi 300 acpi -b|egrep -o '[0-9][0-9]'}
  ${exec mplayer -really-quiet /my/sda3/Sarah*&}
${endif}
```

Any idea how to do this? I get:
*Conky: Bad arguments: '95 ' and ' execi 300 acpi -b|egrep -o '[0-9][0-9]'*'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should work for you:

```
${if_match "95" >= "${execi 300 acpi -b|egrep -o '[0-9][0-9]'}"}
  ${texeci 60 mplayer -really-quiet /my/sda3/Sarah*&}
${endif}
```

At least on my system I must use `${texeci}` (threaded), otherwise the conky window will only appear as a 1-pixel image, so it's important that `mplayer` does not only run as a separate *job* (`&` identifier), but also as separate *thread* in order not to interfere with conky.